# Cache npm packages in Docker GitHub actions

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, caching, github-actions

I actually have GitHub actions that tests a nodeJS project in a Docker image (`node:16-alpine`). My problem is that at each run, `yarn install` re-installed completely all the packages. My question is: how can I cache these packages between runs ?

I've trouble doing it since the execution run in the Docker image and I could not find a solution to cache the packages. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Here is ready to use solution: https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/main/examples.md#node---yarn

Answer (score 1):

You can use [github actions cache](https://github.com/actions/cache) to cache things inside your job.

If you're using a docker image separately from your job, probably you can't cache that. My suggestion, improve your workflow if you create a job for a test and need the same environment put it all in just one `job` with different `steps`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll see if it works well for my project!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dockerCache](https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/backends/gha/) , using that you will be use your github action cache in the respective docker build.